# Is it correct to encapsulate KafkaTemplate/handling methods in your own wrapper(and how)?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, spring-kafka, design-principles

I try to introduce **apache Kafka** to our project and change projects architecture to **producer-consumer**. I experiment on a new test project. For example, I have one producer and two consumers. It is different spring-boot applications(microservices).

In producer service, I need to configure Kafka, create `KafkaTemplate`. In each consumer, I need to configure Kafka and create handlers(methods with `@KafkaListener` annotation).

For example, tomorrow we will want to change Kafka to something another, we will change `KafkaTemplate` and methods with `@KafkaListener` annotation to an implementation of a new library. This is not a good approach. So I consider that we need to create our wrapper. Something like this:

```
public interface EventBus {
    void sendMessage(String topicName, String message);
}
```

And encapsulate KafkaTemplate in the implementation of this interface(`KafkaEventBus implements EventBus`)

I start to implement it but I faced the fact that I do not understand how to do it. I create a Gradle module with 'event-bus' name. This module is not spring - just java module. I create `EventBus` interface and implement it:

```
public class KafkaEventBus implements EventBus {

    private final KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer;

    public KafkaEventBus() {
        this.kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(producerConfig());
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String topicName, String message) {
        kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,message));
    }

    private Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return configProps;
    }
}
```

And stuck. I have questions:

1) Do I need to create a different module(event-bus)? Do I think right?

2) How can implement message handling in this module? If sending something is clear(encapsulate `KafkaTemplate` and delegate message to it) then with handling 
ничего не понятно
nothing is clear.

Maybe, Are there some examples of this, best practices?